# Overlay on navigation in Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, design, android-app

When navigating between Feed and different Stack Exchange sites in the Stack Exchange Android app, I often find myself with a distorted view. It looks like the Feed stays on the screen and whatever view I'm navigating to just overlays it.

App version 1.0.77.

Error is visible on a tablet MyTab Q10 Permium, running Android 4.4.2 (kernel v. 3.4.67).

[image: Overlaid image]

Comment: How can this be a duplicate? Surely the OP has an updated app after the previous problem was fixed almost 1 year ago...

Comment: App is freshly installed from Google Play, version 1.0.77.

Comment: This is very curious. I had exactly the same problem on my tablet and phone. Both run fresh installs of 1.0.77. To ensure that I have latest version of application I have just re-installed it on my phone and now I can't trigger the problem there (on the phone) anymore.

Comment: Adding information about your mobile phone can be useful for solving the bug

Comment: You are right @spund3, silly of me to not include it on first place. Edited the post.

Comment: @Koder Don't worry, i think it's your first time here reporting a bug, right?

Comment: I've seen this before on my 2013 Nexus 7 but I was never able to reproduce it reliably, is it happening reliably for you on your tablet? Does any action cause it to happen?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Not reliably. It seems to be netowork or backend - related. Yesterday it happened every 10-15 mins, today only twice. And I did **not** re-install client on my tablet, it's the same version that had error.

Comment: I think it might be related to coming into the app after it's been opened and gone into a paused state (a warm open vs a cold app open with nothing in memory already related to it) or flipping orientation... I'll play around on my tablet more to see if I can repro it. It's definitely a real bug, somewhere, I just don't know where to edit in the code to fix it yet.

Comment: @spund3 While it's true i rarely file bug reports, i'm often at receiving end and I should really know better. My only excuse is that it seemed webview-related (so hardware/software version shouldn't make so much difference) and I was on sick leave while reporting this. Anyway, I really should have known better.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I managed to reproduce it right now. I changed my SO view to "Unanswered (my tags)", pulled down to refresh and clicked few times on "feed" and "stack overflow" back-and-forth. App was not in paused state and no orientation change during this.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi it's unfortunately nor reliable, i cannot reproduce it second time. I'll wager there is some race in network-related code, but it's wild guess.

Comment: This is great, thank you. I think it's caused by us using transparent Android Fragments, but those are never supposed to be interlaced ontop of each other it's supposed to be one in the view at a time..

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi following on network hypothesis, while my network is saturated (via speedtest.net) it seems a lot easier to replicate - i managed to do so few times. I have no reliable way to setup network throttling for my tablet at home, but it seems to be an promising approach.

Comment: Awesome, I have some easy throttling tools for my tablet, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @PythonMaster This cannot be a duplicate of the other bug as that was using the mobile site in a browser and this is in the native Android app.

Comment: Agreed, removing close vote